# Parse several XML-files with batch

Tags: java, xml, batch-file, xslt, saxon

I want to parse several/all files in a specific folder.

I usually parse my files like this:

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -o:index.html -s:File.xml -xsl:Stylesheet.xslt
pause
```

Is there a way I can parse more than one file at once?

I tried something like this, but it won't work

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -o:index.html -s:Folder/*.xml -xsl:Stylesheet.xslt
pause
```

Comment: It would seem the docs say that [you can use a directory as input/output](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!using-xsl/commandline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use wildcards to identify the files. If you want to parse several files, you must put all of them in a directory, then use *-s:path_to_directory* option along with *-o:path_to_output_file* option.

Doing this you'll parse all the files in the chosen directory.

Answer (score 0):

The other (and more flexible) way of doing it is to control the processing from within the stylesheet, along the lines of:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="collection('folder/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')" mode="one-doc"/>

<xsl:template match="/" mode="one-doc">
  <xsl:result-document href="out/{....}.xml">
    ....
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```